Layers of pre-made maps shapefile not overlapping but reprojecting doesn't do anything
I am a very recent, self-taught user of QGIS.
I have a few map layers of one country with different factors/aspects (admin boundaries, flood risk etc). I sourced them online and they are apparently in the same CRS. When loaded they end up in the same place, however, when placed over the world topographic map and over each other, I can see that there is a tiny shift in layer of flooding risk compared to the outline of the country (they should align). The shift is under 10 km at most and not equal along the entire outline, actually it increases in one region as if the shapefile of that flooding risk was somehow warped.
The administrative boundary overlaps perfectly with the topographic map as well as some other layers I have sourced independently (like elevation). I tried to reproject in QGIS and it didn't fix it.
How do I get that flood layer to overlap properly with the country outline?

The tools and methods are different for reprojecting in each software. Pick one, and tell us exactly how you reprojected your data.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. The most frequent comments here are "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" We are not a tutorial site. Please [Edit] the Question to specify One software stack, provide extensive details on the unmatched datasets, and detail the exact procedure you have used to try to address your problem. Ten kilometers is a huge registration issue -- your datasets may not be usable together.

Do you know how the flood layer was created and what was its intended use ? if digitized from a small scale country wide map or destined for a small scale country wide map, a 10km error may have been acceptable...

I don't know specifically how it was created, it comes from the governemnt-issued maps so I hoped the quality would be appropriate. It is likely that although it was rendered in something like GIS, the file I have is a digitalisation of a pdf version of that map.
